# Delay a task without affecting some prior dependent code in Python

Tags: python

Apologies to the seemingly irrelevant title, but I have no idea what would be a good one.

I'm writing a Python script that takes in raw PCM from `stdin`, analyze it for my RGB LED to flash accordingly. The thing generally looks like this:

```
import alsaaudio, sys

# opening output stream
stream = alsaaudio.PCM()
while True:
   # get raw PCM data from stdin
   data  = sys.stdin.read(BUFFER_RATE)
   # output to speakers immediately to reduce offset with lighting
   stream.write(data)
   # analyze audio data to get lighting parameters
   r,g,b = analyze(data)
   # lastly, set the color of the LED
   led.setColor(r,g,b)
```

However, the lighting seems to be having an offset - it gets updated earlier than the the audio output. `sleep`, `while` loops checking time past, or even opening new threads stutter my audio output. The whole loop is almost inseparable, so I'm kind of at a dead end. I'm not good with interdependent threading, so if that might be a good solution, please enlighten me.

EDIT: according to a suggestion in an answer below, I set the PCM period size with `stream.setperiodsize(BUFFER_RATE)`. The lag is noticeably reduced, but still really evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html#alsaaudio.PCM.write):

> **PCM.write(data)**
>   Writes (plays) the sound in data. The length of data must be a multiple of the frame size, and should be exactly the
>   size of a period. If less than ‘period size’ frames are provided, the
>   actual playout will not happen until more data is written.

---

> **A few hints on using PCM devices for playback**
>
> The most common reason for problems with playback of PCM audio is that
>   writes to PCM devices must exactly match the **data rate of the device**.

From the [PCM terminology](http://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/terminology.html) page:

> **Data rate**   This is the number of bytes, which must be recorded or provided per second at a certain frame size and rate.
>
> 8000 Hz mono sound with 8 bit (1 byte) samples has a data rate of 8000
>   * 1 * 1 = 8 kb/s or 64kbit/s. This is typically used for telephony.
>
> At the other end of the scale, 96000 Hz, 6 channel sound with 64 bit
>   (8 bytes) samples has a data rate of 96000 * 6 * 8 = 4608 kb/s (almost
>   5 Mb sound data per second)

Also:

> **Period**
>   When the hardware processes data this is done in chunks of frames. The
>   time interval between each processing (A/D or D/A conversion) is known
>   as the period. The size of the period has direct implication on the
>   latency of the sound input or output. **For low-latency the period size
>   should be very small**, while low CPU resource usage would usually
>   demand larger period sizes. With ALSA, the CPU utilization is not
>   impacted much by the period size, since the kernel layer buffers
>   multiple periods internally, so each period generates an interrupt and
>   a memory copy, but userspace can be slower and read or write multiple
>   periods at the same time.
>
> **Period size**
>   This is the size of each period in Hz. Not bytes, but Hz!. In alsaaudio the period size is set directly, and it is
>   therefore important to understand the significance of this number. If
>   the period size is configured to for example 32, each write should
>   contain exactly 32 frames of sound data, and each read will return
>   either 32 frames of data or nothing at all.

Comment: the problem is possibly not in the audio output - it outputs fine with `BUFFER _RATE` set to anything from 2 ** 10 to 2 ** 12. No clicking, blocking or zeroing happens whatsoever. Also, the default frame size is 32, and all the buffer rate I set are powers of 2, which is a multiple of 32.

Comment: never mind my last comment - I set the period size to be `BUFFER_RATE`, and the lag is reduced by almost half. However it is still really recognizable. Is there anything else I should know/fix?

Comment: a little trial-and-error with setting the period size to the 1/2 and 1/4 reduce the lag to a minimal. setting `stream.setperiodsize(BUFFER_RATE/4)` helped a lot. marked as accepted answer, thank you very much.